# postgres dump with inserts but without copy actions

Tags: postgresql, dump, pg-dump

I am trying to dump my database.

For reasons I can't go into detail here, I am unable to use the "Copy" function. This means that the insert statements have to be "pure" insert. However, I am not sure how to reflect this in my dump.

Currently, this is my dump command:

```
 pg_dump -U myUser --column-inserts --data-only  -h localhost my_db> backup
```

Can anyone tell me how i might get the insert statements without the `Copy` function?

Comment: That's what `--column-inserts` is for, and it seems to work just fine for me... Double-check that you ran the right command, and are looking at the right backup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The documentation of `pg_dumps`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/app-pgdump.html) tells us this:

> `--inserts`
>
> Dump data as INSERT commands (rather than COPY). This will make restoration very slow; it is mainly useful for making dumps that can be loaded into non-PostgreSQL databases. However, since this option generates a separate command for each row, an error in reloading a row causes only that row to be lost rather than the entire table contents. Note that the restore might fail altogether if you have rearranged column order. The --column-inserts option is safe against column order changes, though even slower.

Comment: The command in the question is already using `--column-inserts`, sounds to me like there's something else going on here...

Comment: No, `--column-inserts` is not the same as `--inserts`. It only instructs `pg_dump` to use explicit column names *if* an `INSERT` is part of the dump. It does not instruct the usage of `INSERT` over `COPY`.

Comment: Strange. The OP already accepted this answer so it looks like it helped. But you are right that both options help. I've tested this, too.

Comment: some version of greenplum seems can't  dump data with `pg_dump --inserts --column-inserts`